# useDispatch vs store.dispatch

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a React component and I am dispatching an action via the react-redux useDispatch hook.

Is there any practical difference if I dispatch the action in a separate util file and access the dispatch method on the store directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `store.dispatch` is the actual `dispatch` function that is also provided by your `connect` and `useDispatch` APIs.
Yes, you can use `store.dispatch` from some another file as well.

```
const store = createStore(reducer);

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

setInterval(() => {
  store.dispatch(addTodo(new Date().toLocaleTimeString()));
}, 5000);
```

I am adding a new item in todo above every 5 seconds using `store.dispatch` and it works fine.

You can check code at https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-pateu-hnjtfh?file=/src/index.js:283-511

[image]